# Push new value into existing array in specific position React Hooks

Tags: arrays, react-hooks

I have `for` loop where I am getting status of each user if he is online or not, and I need to put that status into existing array

```
const user = [
  {
    "name":"John",
    "lastname":"smith"
  },
  {
    "name":"Melissa",
    "lastname":"Ryan"
  }
]
```

I tried on this way but I have error

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          const dataR = {
            order: result[i].userID
          };
          const options = {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json",
              "Content-type": "application/json",
              Authentication: user.getHmac("POST", "/api/getonline"),
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(dataR),
          };
          fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_DB_URI + "/getonline", options)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => {
      
              console.error("Error:", error)
            })
            .then(response => {
              if (response) {
                user[i].push({online:response}); <---problem
             }


}
```

ERROR:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of
> undefined

How to push new value online into user array?

Comment: Please post the error you're getting

Comment: I updated question with errror. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user[i]` being undefined means you're indexing it outside of where it is defined.  For example, this can be from `result.length` being longer than your user array.

However your approach won't work in general because `user[i]` is not an array, so you can't push to it.  To put that data into the array with an `online` property to the `user` object, this can be achieved by

`user[i] = {...user[i], online: response};`